# Can a file from a read-only partition be mounted as volume in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I am deploying applications using docker in a context where most system files and folders are in a read-only partition.

For one particular container, I need to set a file (/etc/hosts) as a read-only volume. This file is located in a read-only partition. Problem is that it seems to be not possible to do so, and I couldn't find any documentation in docker about this particular case.

This is the error I get from docker-compose:

`Cannot start service core: chown /etc/hosts: read-only file system`

Everything works fine if the partition is set to be read-write, but this is not an acceptable solution for the production environment.

This is the extract of the docker-compose used that can be used to reproduce this issue:

```
version: '2'
services:
 core:
  image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  privileged: true
  volumes:
   - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
  restart: always
```

Comment: You first tell docker to treat `/etc/hosts` as read only, then you try to modify it, I guess your really make docker stumped.

Comment: The application is not trying to modify the file. Actually, the container does not even starts. A "chown" command is triggered by docker (or docker-compose) automatically, whose fail prevents the container from starting at all.

Comment: I simply try it with `docker run -it -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash`, did not find any issue, maybe your image has some special. No idea, wait others.

Answer (score 0):

The daemon attempts to change the ownership of the exported file.  Perhaps, this is done to have proper permission limits.

https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/442b45628ee12ebd8e8bd08497896d5fa8eec4bd#diff-23d6e820e60770582745d99d54e0c5cd4c229ae2ae5780c58cc137733099c434

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/2b70006e3bfa492b8641ff443493983d832955f4/daemon/initlayer/setup_unix.go#L59

I can imagine that the container, having privileges to access host devices, may be tricked to affect these device by a malicious non-privileged user of the host who could modify the file that is exported from the host.  (In your case, the file is probably already owned by host's `root`, but the daemon appears to attempt the needless `chown` for the same `root` user and fails only due to the read-only requirement).  Perhaps, the Docker daemon's Github project could use a pull request where the `chown` call is spared for read-only mounts and/or for the entries that are already owned by the target user.